# R: Attach result matrix to all lists in environment

Tags: r, list, matrix

(I´d ask in chat first, however my karma is not sufficient.)

I have lists that contain matrices, say:

```
List1 <- list(ch1 = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2), ch2 = matrix(5:8, ncol = 2))
List2 <- list(ch1 = matrix(2:5, ncol = 2), ch2 = matrix(6:9, ncol = 2))
```

I now want to perform calculations for all the lists in my environment and append the results as another matrix in the corresponding list. Let´s say ch3 should be ch1 + ch2, so List1 would look like:

```
$ch1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$ch2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

$ch3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   10
[2,]    8   12
```

As length of lists vary, I have to address the matrices by name, ch1 and so forth.

My approach gets the result right, however not appended as a matrix, but as integers. Fixing this is cumbersome, so there surely is a better approach.

```
LST <- objects(pattern = "List+(\\d+)", envir = globalenv())

for (i in 1:length(LST)){
  pointer1 <- which(names(get(LST[[i]])) == "ch1")
  pointer2 <- which(names(get(LST[[i]])) == "ch2")

  matrix1 <- get(LST[[i]])[pointer1][[1]]
  matrix2 <- get(LST[[i]])[pointer2][[1]]

  result <- matrix1 + matrix2
  # print(dim(result))# results in 2 2, as expected

  assign(LST[[i]], c(get(LST[[i]]), matrix(result, ncol = ncol(matrix1))))

  # rm(pointer1, pointer2, matrix1, matrix2, result)
}
```

As each of my approx. 100 lists consist of more than 15 matrices of up to 300MB each, I cannot merge them into an array due to memory restrictions. Ideally, I would end up having a function or something neat as lapply, however, I can get neither one to work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked it out. Had to code in more steps than intended, for some reason it only works like this. Consider the following:

```
List1 <- list(ch1 = matrix(1:4, ncol = 2), ch2 = matrix(5:8, ncol = 2))
List2 <- list(ch1 = matrix(2:5, ncol = 2), ch2 = matrix(6:9, ncol = 2))

LST <- objects(pattern = "List+(\\d+)", envir = globalenv())

for (i in 1:length(LST)){
  pointer1 <- which(names(get(LST[[i]])) == "ch1")
  pointer2 <- which(names(get(LST[[i]])) == "ch2")

  matrix1 <- get(LST[[i]])[pointer1][[1]]
  matrix2 <- get(LST[[i]])[pointer2][[1]]

  result <- matrix1 + matrix2

  tmpList <- get(LST[[i]])

  ListLength <- length(tmpList)
  chNames <- names(tmpList)
  chNames <- c(chNames, "ch3")

  tmpList[[ListLength + 1]] <- result

  names(tmpList) <- chNames

  assign(LST[[i]], tmpList)
}
rm(i, ListLength, LST, pointer1, pointer2, matrix1, matrix2, result, chNames, tmpList)
```

Produces desired result:

```
> List1
$ch1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

$ch2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    7
[2,]    6    8

$ch3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6   10
[2,]    8   12

> List2
$ch1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    4
[2,]    3    5

$ch2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    6    8
[2,]    7    9

$ch3
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    8   12
[2,]   10   14
```